# sum number ( infinite paramater ) using caporal npm javascript

Tags: javascript, npm

I want to know how to sum number ( infinite parameter ) using caporal npm

```
var prog = require('caporal');

prog
    .version('1.0.0')
    .command('sum', 'inputnumber')
    .argument('[env...]', 'Other environments')
    .action((args) => {
        env:[]
        console.log(args);
    })

prog.parse(process.argv);

this will print 
./cli sum 1 2 3 4
{ env: [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ] }
```

how to split that array and sum it ?

i already know how to sum using 2 parameter ( definded parameter )

```
var prog = require('caporal');
prog
    .version('1.0.0')
    .command('sum', 'inputnumber')
    .argument('<n1>','first number')
    .argument('<n2>','second number')
    .action(function(args) {
        var result = parseInt(args.n1) + parseInt(args.n2);
        console.log(result);
    });

    prog.parse(process.argv);

./cli sum 1 2
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closed , i found solution myself

```
 prog
        .version('1.0.0')
        .command('sum', 'inputtext')
        .argument('[env...]', 'Other environments')
        .action((args) => {
            var s = 0;
            for(var i=0; i<args.env.length; i++)
                s += parseInt(args.env[i]);
            console.log(s);
        })

    prog.parse(process.argv);

    ./cli sum 1 2 3 4
    10
```